# Calculate the machine epsilon in Matlab

Tags: matlab, precision

How can I calculate the machine epsilon for two numbers then calculate the theoretical limit for machine epsilon in Matlab ?

Comment: Could you perhaps define what you mean by "theoretical limit for machine epsilon" here? A limit is defined with respect to a variable tending to some (possibly infinite) value; what is tending where, here?

Answer (score 2):

So, machine epsilon is an upper bound on the relative error due to roundoff. You can calculate this quantity using the `eps` function:

```
 eps
        2.2204e-16
```

If you want to find the distance between a floating point number `x` and the next nearest floating point number, you would call `eps(x)` instead.

Comment: Right I get that but say I have the number 124 and 120 if I did eps (124) and esp(120) how would I calculate the theoretical limit for machine eps?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying when you talk about "the theoretical limit for machine epsilon". That maximum relative error is `eps`, which is the limit of `eps(x)/x` as `abs(x)` approaches infinity; it's also `eps(1)`.

Comment: Do you have any ideas what the theoretical limit for machine epsilon could mean? Because that is what my hw questions ask to find and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Each floating point representation has defined limits (including epsilon) based on the number of bits of exponent, mantissa, and how the signs are represented. Maybe you could give the exact form of the question.

Comment: `eps(x)`: a.k.a. [ULP (unit in last place)](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place).

Comment: We are given a the largest 10 bit signed mantissa-exponent  possible and the smallest 10 bit signed mantissa-exponent possible and it wants me to calculate machine epsilon for both the largest number and the smallest number and then use these values to find the theoretical limit for machine epsilon

Comment: @Rain: You should a) put that information in the question, and b) clearly state that your question is a homework question, because it's site policy.